# CLion Documentation prompt no longer provides full reference material

Tags: c, clion

When hitting Ctrl+Q I would get dozens of paragraphs of documentation from CLion which if I'm not mistaken was the GNU reference manual.  Now after a simple restart I'm only getting what's included in the headers, which is often times a brief and quite useless description.  May I have disabled this feature somehow by pressing a shortcut?  Any way to re-enable?  The reference was priceless for me.

Comment: Seems it's your case https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-20110

Comment: Thanks Maxim.  Seems like no solution in sight, that's quite unfortunate.  I added a comment to the issue in the hopes it gets noticed quicker.